# FX 2 Set padding in a line chart plot

Tags: charts, javafx-2

I have a XY line chart plot and a css file where I set chart features.

I can't figure out how to avoid the white border along the chart

[image]

My css settings are:

```
.chart-plot-background{
-fx-padding:0px;
-fx-font-family: Verdana;
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom right, lightsteelblue, black);
}
.chart-content{
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom right, lightsteelblue, black);
-fx-padding:30px;
}
```

I would like to fill the frame with same color without the white border.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any chance that your chart is in another container with a margin and that container is what's white?

Comment: Yes my chart is plotted on a JInternaFrame, maybe this is the reason for I see a white border: what I do not know is WHY my chart doesn't fill all the JinternalFrame area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a solution: it seems these white lines act as "border", so I have added in css file these instructions:

```
-fx-border-color: linear-gradient(to bottom right, lightsteelblue, black);
-fx-border-width: 5;
-fx-border-insets: -5;
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, any suggestions appreciated.